# SDWebImage Prefetching with completion block

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

My aim is to cover a collectionView with a 'loading screen' which will not be hidden until all the images from a pre-fetched array of images have been loaded into cache by SDWebImage.

In my viewDidLoad I have retrieved an array of image URL's which will be used to populate a collection view. Once they are retrieved I plan on using SDWebImagePrefetcher to process the array.

so far I have the below:

```
let urls : [URL] = [URL(string: "https://trialwebsite.com/image1.png")!,URL(string: "https://trialwebsite.com/image2.png")!,URL(string: "https://trialwebsite.com/image3.png")!]

 SDWebImagePrefetcher.shared().prefetchURLs(urls)
```

What I am struggling to figure out is how to use a completion block to hide the 'loading' screen once all the images have been processed.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`prefetchURLs:completed:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/3.3/Classes/SDWebImagePrefetcher.html#//api/name/prefetchURLs:completed:) instead of using `prefetchURLs`, it would has a completion block (closure since you are writing Swift) parameter that contains `finishedCount` and `skippedCount` unsigned integers:

as mentioned in the method documentation:

> **completionBlock**
>
> block to be called when prefetching is completed

which is seems to be what are you asking for. So it would be something like:

```
SDWebImagePrefetcher.shared().prefetchURLs(urls) { finishedCount, skippedCount in
    // hide the 'loading' screen...
    // you might need to implement your own counting logic 
    // to make sure that all images have been processed.
}
```

Comment: How do you cancel a specific prefetch with SDWedImagePrefetcher according to IndexPath?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift v4.1 & SDWebImage v3.8.2

```
SDWebImagePrefetcher.shared().prefetchURLs(arrayOfURLS, progress: nil, completed: { finishedCount, skippedCount in
        print("Prefetch complete!")
    })
```